# How to get multiple waveforms in ltspice

Tags: pspice

I'm doing the CMOS inverter simulation. My circuit and waveforms are correct. But I want the waveform for the different Vtc values and also the different Length and width. If I am changing any data like Vdd and L and w the previous waveform gets changed to the new one but I want the new as well old both waveform. Please give me some advice.
[Circuit Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLzBs.jpg)

[Waveform for Vdd=2V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/affIQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Draw two schematic on single page one without sweeping parameters and another sweeping (changing) parameters. Probe both schematic nodes in waveform window to compare

Another alternative is you can export the probe data in .txt right click on wave form window> file > export as txt. To plot in other simulators or libre cal/MS excel